# Grails domain custom validator check uniqueness

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Can you check combination uniqueness of a field inside a custom validator in a Grails domain class?

```
Long points
String field1
String field2 
Level level

level validator {val,obj->

if(obj.points<1000){
    //make sure level is unique with field 1
    level unique: ['field1']
}
else{
    //make sure level is unique with field 2
    level unique: ['field2']
}

}
```

Comment: You cannot specify uniqueness this way. Remember that uniqueness is specifed at database level and you cannot do that in a database.

Comment: so I would have to run a query and check if that combo existed already?...findWhere(level:val,field1:object.field1)?//valid://error

Comment: Yeah! In this case you have to create a customizable solution to ensure uniqueness in your application. Keep in mind if you want uniqueness in the database you'll need two tables (a table containing Field1 + Level and other table containing Field2 + Level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The unique constraint is a DDL constraint. It means Grails/Hibernate will create an unique index in your database schema when your app starts, so the constraint remains immutable. The validator constraint is just a closure and it will be executed at runtime every time your domain class is validated.

You have to validate the uniqueness yourself checking the entity in your database using a finder or criteria, rejecting with an error if the unique condition already exists. In your finders, don't forget to exclude the record you are validating.